# How can I access 3rd party tracking parameters within a page (via Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, google-analytics

I have searched quite a bit and so far unable to determine how to access 3rd party tracking parameters within a page. With the code below I can access the cookies of the page via the python requests package, but only for the local domain, none of the 3rd party cookies/domains is returned:

```
import requests
# create session
s = requests.session()
# read data from a page
r = s.get('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
# show cookies and the domain that the cookies belongs to
print('>> printing cookies ...')
for cookie in s.cookies:
    print(cookie)
    print('domain=' + cookie.domain)
    print('   ck_name: ' + cookie.name)
    print('   ck_val:  ' + cookie.value)
    print('   expires: ' + str(cookie.expires))
print()    
# paramaters come back empty ...
print('>> printing parameters ...')
for param in s.params:
    print(param)
```

I also tried via Selenium with the Chrome driver:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'{path}\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
print('Page opened ...')
# here I can access the page HTML and local session via the driver variable
driver.quit()   # close page
```

but the 3rd part tracking parameters elude me. To clarify, on the page https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/ Chomrt Dev tools show that there is a Google Analytics collector that runs and returns the parameters as per this image:

[image: GA collection parameter]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be read only from the domain from which they were set, that's just the way cookies work.

Google Analytics does not use data from 3rd party cookies. The only cookie it needs to function is the _ga cookie with the clientId and that is a first party cookie set by an injected javascript.

Comment: Thank you Eike. As far as I understand, since google drops the _ga cookie onto the test website ([https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/](https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/) in my code), that makes it a 3rd party cookie. Regardless, my issue is that the python code I have (and other methods from online searches) do not provide the _ga cookie info. Do you have a method to extract that value?

Comment: No. The Google Analytics Javascript is injected into the page. Thus it becomes a part of the page code, and sets cookies as first party cookies on that domain. Also it does not store any other information in the cookie than the client id (the previous GA version stored data clientside, but that is deprecated). If you want to get at the data you would need to capture the outgoing request to google-analytics.com, not the cookie.

Comment: Thank you for the response Eike. And yes, I am trying to get to the outgoing responses (parameters) sent to google-analytics.com via the "collect" as per `https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j54&a=312617887&t=pageview&_s=1&...`. The code I stated above does not access these HTTP response information. Any advice on how I can get to that will be greatly appreciated.